# Which user will be used when setting SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials to true in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, smtpclient

In an ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC application, if I send an e-mail using [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4971yhhc.aspx) with [`UseDefaultCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials) set to `true`, which user will be used to authenticate with the mail server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the [`UseDefaultCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials.aspx) property is set to `true`, [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4971yhhc.aspx) will use the credentials provided to the 
[`DefaultCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials.aspx) property in the [`CredentialCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.aspx) class.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials.aspx):

> For ASP.NET applications, **the default credentials are the user credentials of the logged-in user, or the user being impersonated**.